# A converse of the maximum modulus Theorem

Tags: cv.complex-variables, reference-request

W. Rudin in  *Real and Complex Analysis* (262) mentioned that

> **Theorem** Suppose $M$ is a vector space of continuous complex functions
> on the closed unit disc $\bar U$, with
> the following properties:
>
> (a) $1 \in M$
>
> (b) If $f \in M$,then also $jf \in
> M$, where $j$ denotes the identity
> function: $j(z)=z$.
>
> (c) If $f \in M$, then
> $\lVert f\rVert_U=\lVert f\rVert_T$, where T is the
> boundary of $\bar U$.
>
> Then every $f\in M$ is holomorphic in
> $U$.

What I interested in is the origin and extension of this theorem. Where did it come form?
Are there any references about this?

Comment: I added the [reference-request] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the notes and comments section at the end of Real and Complex Analysis (page 397 in my copy), Rudin attributes this result "in a slightly different form" to:

W. Rudin, [Analyticity, and the maximum modulus principle](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-20/issue-3/Analyticity-and-the-maximum-modulus-principle/10.1215/S0012-7094-53-02045-6.short). Duke Math. J. 20, (1953). 449–457.